# What reaction took place?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

Okay, so I was fiddling about in the chemistry lab, and I added:
Sodium Nitroprusside (soln) $\ce{Na_2[Fe(CN)_5NO]}$ with Potassium Ferrocyanide (soln) $\ce{K_4[Fe(CN)_6]}$.

$\ce{Na_2[Fe(CN)_5NO]}$ was a yellowish-reddish colour - actually don't remember the *exact colour*, while $\ce{K_4[Fe(CN)_6]}$ was pale yellow.

Nothing really happened to the mixture - except the colours mixed giving a weird yellow colour. I assume the only thing that happened was a double decomposition reaction:

$\ce{K_4[Fe(CN)_6] + Na_2[Fe(CN)_5NO] \rightarrow K_2[Fe(CN)_5NO] + Na_4[Fe(CN)_6]}$
or something like that.

Next I added a bit of dil Hydrochloric Acid. I expected nothing to happen - nothing ever happens with the chemicals they keep in labs. :P However, the colour of the mixture turned a beautiful Emerald Green!

Now I've been trying to figure out what exactly occured to produce the green colour, but I don't know. Could anyone help me?

$P.S.$ My friend's gonna send me a picture of the green we took. I'll edit it to the question when I recieve it, maybe it will help?

Comment: It should be noted that this is a potentially very dangerous experiment.  Addition of a strong acid (note that a dilute strong acid is **still a strong acid**) to ferrocyanide can lead to the generation of hydrogen cyanide gas, which is extremely toxic.

Comment: Whoa. :O I did **NOT** know that. Thankfully, HCN _wasn't_ formed. ***Phew***. Thanks for the info! :D 
P.S. Any idea why the green in colour was formed?

Comment: sodium ferrocyanide is green in colour. see this:-https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sodium+ferrocyanide&biw=1360&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiGvI6ipaLMAhXJLpQKHT3zA2IQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1